# PBEWITHHMACSHA256ANDAES_256 encryption throws EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException

Tags: java, encryption, aes, jasypt, sha2

I'd like to use the `PBEWITHHMACSHA256ANDAES_256` algorithm but it's not supported. I've added the [bouncy castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) provider to my test in the hopes that it will work but to no avail. Can anyone please tell me how to fix the test below such that `PBEWITHHMACSHA256ANDAES` is added to the `Supported` list?

```
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor;
import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.SimpleStringPBEConfig;
import org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException;
import org.jasypt.registry.AlgorithmRegistry;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class EncryptionTest {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Set<String> supported = new TreeSet<>();
        Set<String> unsupported = new TreeSet<>();
        for (Object oAlgorithm : AlgorithmRegistry.getAllPBEAlgorithms()) {
            String algorithm = (String) oAlgorithm;
            try {
                SimpleStringPBEConfig pbeConfig = new SimpleStringPBEConfig();
                pbeConfig.setAlgorithm(algorithm);
                pbeConfig.setPassword("changeme");
                StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
                encryptor.setConfig(pbeConfig);

                String encrypted = encryptor.encrypt("foo");
                String decrypted = encryptor.decrypt(encrypted);
                Assert.assertEquals("foo", decrypted);
                supported.add(algorithm);
            } catch (EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException e) {
                unsupported.add(algorithm);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Supported");
        supported.forEach((String alg) -> System.out.println("   " + alg)); 
        System.out.println("Unsupported");
        unsupported.forEach((String alg) -> System.out.println("   " + alg)); 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Supported
   PBEWITHMD2ANDDES
   PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
   PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
   PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
   PBEWITHSHA1ANDDESEDE
   PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
   PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2_128
   PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2_40
   PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC4_128
   PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC4_40
Unsupported
   PBEWITHHMACSHA1ANDAES_128
   PBEWITHHMACSHA1ANDAES_256
   PBEWITHHMACSHA224ANDAES_128
   PBEWITHHMACSHA224ANDAES_256
   PBEWITHHMACSHA256ANDAES_128
   PBEWITHHMACSHA256ANDAES_256
   PBEWITHHMACSHA384ANDAES_128
   PBEWITHHMACSHA384ANDAES_256
   PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_128
   PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_256
   PBEWITHMD5ANDTRIPLEDES
   PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
   PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
   PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
   PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
   PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
   PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
   PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
   PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
   PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
   PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
   PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
   PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
   PBEWITHSHAANDIDEA-CBC
   PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
```

*** Edit ***

@EbbeMPedersen suggested that this algorithm is provided by SunJCE but I can see that SunJCE provider is enabled using the following code

```
for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
    System.out.println(provider.getName() + " " + provider.getClass().getName());
}
```

Output

```
SUN sun.security.provider.Sun
SunRsaSign sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
SunEC sun.security.ec.SunEC
SunJSSE com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
SunJCE com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
SunJGSS sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
SunSASL com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
XMLDSig org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
SunPCSC sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
SunMSCAPI sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI
BC org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Comment: Take a look at BouncyCastle supported algorithms [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) .. PBEWITHHMACSHA256ANDAES_256 is not on the list. It might pop up in the list from another security provider

Comment: It's e.g. part of [SunJCE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJCEProvider)

Comment: Please see my edit, `com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE` is in the array returned by `Security.getProviders()`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that Jasypt is not able to retain the derived `AlgorithmParameters` and re-use them when switching the cipher between `ENCRYPT` and `DECRYPT`. The underlying exception that Jasypt is obscuring is `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Missing parameter type: IV expected`, but if you provide the `salt` (or `SaltGenerator` in this case) and `key obtention iterations` (i.e. the number of times to invoke the `HMAC/SHA-256` "key digest function"), Jasypt still complains because it doesn't understand how to pass the calculated parameters to the decrypt cipher. (You can verify this by debugging your test and putting a breakpoint in `StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java` at line `1055` (Jasypt 1.9.2)) -- here you can catch the underlying exception *and* use the expression window to verify that:

```
encryptCipher.getParameters().getEncoded() -> 306206092a864886f70d01050d3055303406092a864886f70d01050c30270410f5a439e8dc12642972dbbf3e1867edaf020203e8020120300c06082a864886f70d02090500301d060960864801650304012a0410caacd97ae953ae257b1b4a0bb70ccc2e
```

but

```
decryptCipher.getParameters().getEncoded() -> java.security.ProviderException: Could not construct CipherSpi instance
```

Here is a (Groovy) test that demonstrates the failure of Jasypt and the successful method of using your desired algorithm (**note: 1000 iterations is not sufficient for robust security against modern hardware, but for demonstration purposes only**):

```
@Test
void testShouldUseHS256andAES256() {
    // Arrange
    String algorithm = "PBEwithHMACSHA256andAES_256";
    SimpleStringPBEConfig pbeConfig = new SimpleStringPBEConfig();
    pbeConfig.setAlgorithm(algorithm);
    pbeConfig.setPassword("changeme");

    // Need an IV (derived from salt and iteration count)
    // pbeConfig.setKeyObtentionIterations(1000);
    // pbeConfig.setSaltGenerator(new RandomSaltGenerator());

    StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
    encryptor.setConfig(pbeConfig);

    // Act
    def msg = shouldFail(Exception) {
        String encrypted = encryptor.encrypt("foo");

        // Assert
        String decrypted = encryptor.decrypt(encrypted);
        Assert.assertEquals("foo", decrypted);
    }
    logger.info("Expected: ${msg}")

    // Required way
    Cipher rawCipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm)
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec("changeme" as char[])
    final SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    SecretKey tempKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    PBEParameterSpec saltParameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(Hex.decodeHex("0123456789ABCDEF" as char[]), 1000)
    rawCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, tempKey, saltParameterSpec)

    // Save the generated ASN.1-encoded parameters
    byte[] algorithmParameterBytes = rawCipher.getParameters().encoded

    byte[] cipherBytes = rawCipher.doFinal("foo".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

    AlgorithmParameters algorithmParameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(algorithm)
    algorithmParameters.init(algorithmParameterBytes)
    rawCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, tempKey, algorithmParameters)
    byte[] plainBytes = rawCipher.doFinal(cipherBytes)
    String recovered = new String(plainBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

    assert recovered == "foo"
}
```